# What error am I making trying to get my desired UI in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, alignment

I have tried to achieve the effect shown in the highlighted portion of the image with the following code, but this produces counter-intuitive and wrong results.

Just to avoid confusion, I am talking about the effect of the middle of the smaller containers being aligned with the bottom of the large orange-ish container

My code is as follows:

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: height * (3 / 5) - height * 0.15 / 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: height * 0.15,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: height * 0.15,
                  width: width * 0.45,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: height * 0.15,
                  width: width * 0.45,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

How can I improve upon my code?[image]

Comment: use Stack to get this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the *Stack* widget to achieve this result.

```
 Stack(children: [
          Container(
              height: 230,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
              )),
          Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22))),
                    Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22))),
                    Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22))),
                  ]),
            ),
          ])
        ])
```